# jQuery Rotate Function with jcrop

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I am using jcrop with jquery but also want to use jQueryRotate(2.2).Cropping is working fine but rotate is not working.I have two button 1)crop and another for rotate.The rotate will rotate image clockwise and anti clockwise

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" size="4" id="x1" name="x" />
<input type="hidden" size="4" id="y1" name="y" />
<input type="hidden" size="4" id="x2" name="x2" />
<input type="hidden" size="4" id="y2" name="y2" />
<input  type="hidden" size="4" id="w" name="w" />
<input type="hidden" size="4" id="h" name="h" />
<img src="test.jpg" id="photo"  >
 <input type="submit" name="sub12" value="Save Cropped Image" class="save" />
<input type="button" name="rotate1" value="Rotata" onclick="javascript:rot1()"   />
</form>

jQuery(function($){
$('#photo').Jcrop()

});

function rot1()
{
   $("#photo").rotate(45);
}
```

please help

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with the code. Do you get any error message in your browsers console window?

Comment: Is the javascript within `<script>` and `</script>` tags ? or just in the page like the code in your question ? If not that will be the problem. And there is no need for `javascript:` in the `onclick` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can try using like this:

```
jQuery(function(){

  $('#photo').Jcrop();

  $("input[name='rotate1']").click(function() {
     $("#photo").rotate(45);
     return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: What says Google Chrome console ? Press F12 and select `Console` window.

Comment: Use the console window in Firebug which you will now install if you don't already have it.

Comment: Actually it is working fine standalone but problem is coming when use jcrop. Error console showing nothing wrong(FF)

Comment: Is not possible because JS is client-side NOT server-side. Please check PHP code or security server settings.